# How to send message without using bots in telegram

Tags: node.js, telegram

i have been strugling with this for the past few days, i keep getting errors like MIGRATE_PHONE and bad request and the documentation for these errors are really scarce. is there a way i can use the telegram api with node js to send a message to someone without using a telegram bot?
Thanks

Comment: are you willing to use another solution besides node.js?

Comment: sure i would be willing

Comment: consider writing your own client Telegram client from scratch in a language you are comfortable with. There are several posts here on SO to get you started